# URLs are overflowing on tag info

Tags: bug, tags, design, tag-dropdown

When mousing over the description of the [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail) tag, I noticed that the url in the tag info runs off the display box - is this intended?

[image: img1]

In this example, I found one that clearly shows the run-off - this can be a nuisance when there's other text behind it and it appears all jumbled up. Bug?

This is on Google Chrome, Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I don't see this behaviour. Might be browser specific?

Comment: @Larnu Probably - this is on Google Chrome, Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: For reference, issue is not replicated in Firefox 71.0 (64 bit).

Comment: @Lamu because FF breaks at `/` character in `word-break: normal`, so it's not reproducible with that example, but could also happen with an other long word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproduced. Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (32-bit)

The issue is that the width for the tag popup and its container are 348px (container) and 340px (tag popup). Accompanied by this is also a 16px and 12px padding on the internal elements.

As a result, the inner area only has 340 - 32 - 24 pixels of area, 284px. The url text size for *`https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail`* is 347px (by my observation), and so the overflow of 63px presents as shown in the image here.

There are many ways of solving this issue, so I wont present any since the solution will need to factor in to their own internal guidelines.